# Maxima & Minima

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi, how do I find the minimum value of f(x) = (4sin²x + 9cosec²x) using the concepts of maxima and minima? First I used the AM-GM inequality, I got 12, which is the right answer if we take a look at the graph of the function. Then I tried using the concepts of maxima/minima (which is supposed to work too). 
If I differentiate it once and set it equal to zero, it gives me x = (2n+1)π/2, i.e odd multiples of π/2 (check out the attachment). Now if we put x = π/2, 3π/2, 5π/2, etc into the function, it gives me 13 as the answer, which is wrong. It's minimum value is 12. Where did it go wrong? Because concepts of maxima and minima should get us to the correct answer? 
Thanks

Comment: 13 is correct. AM-GM is loose here.

Comment: If you take a look at the graph of this function, it's clear that it's minimum value is 12 and it goes as high as +infinity. How is 13 the correct answer then?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. 13 is the correct answer. Actually I didn't read its graph correctly. My bad! Sorry. And thanks

Comment: Instead of differentiating , you can write the function as : $(2sinx-3cosecx)^2 +12 $. Then you can conclude that the minimum value of $(2sinx-3cosecx)^2$ is $1$ and hence min value of $f(x)$ is 13 . Although this is not the best method.

Comment: How did you conclude that the minimum value of (2sinx - 3cosecx)² is 1? Can you please explain it?

Comment: Did you use Maxima/minima? Or did you just figure it out intuitively? That's what I want to know

Comment: @πtimese Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Using AM-GM inequality,

$$4\sin^2 x + 9 cosec^2 x \ge 2 \sqrt{4\cdot 9}=12$$

However, the equality only holds when $$4 \sin^2 x = 9 cosec^2 x$$ $$\sin^4 x = \frac94$$which is not attainable.

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ifqeqzonkw) link here for the graph.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand it

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

\begin{align*}4\sin^2 x + 9 \csc^2 x&=4\sin^2 x + \frac{9}{ \sin^2 x}\\&=\left(4\sin^2+ \frac{4}{ \sin^2 x}\right)+\frac{5}{\sin^2 x}\\&\geq 2\sqrt{4\sin^2 x\cdot\frac{4}{\sin^2 x}}+5\\&=2\cdot 4+5\\&=13,\end{align*}with the equality holding if and only if $\sin^2 x=1$, namely, $x=2k\pi\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\sin^2x=t^2$ for $t\in[0,1]$, we want to know when $g(t)=4t^2+\frac9{t^2}$ becomes minimal. We have $4t^2+\frac9{t^2} = (\frac3t-2t)^2+12$. Dropping the square gives you the 12. However, $\frac3t-2t\ge 1$ for $0< t\le 1$ and so the function must be at least 13, attained whenever $\sin^2x=1$.

Comment: How to establish the last inequality?

Comment: Calculus works, for example. The derivative of $\frac3t-2t$ is negative for $t>0$, so the function is $\ge$ its value at the rightmost point. But the answer of @mengdie1982 is more elegant anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted we can't apply AM-GM inequality but we can refer to [**Rearrangement inequality**](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Rearrangement_Inequality) selecting

- $(a_1,a_2)=\left(\sin^2 x,\frac94 \right)$
- $(b_1,b_2)=\left(4,\frac{4}{\sin^2 x}\right)$

we have

$$4\sin^2 x + \frac{9}{ \sin^2 x}=4\cdot \sin^2 x + \frac 94\cdot\frac{4}{ \sin^2 x}=$$

$$=a_1b_1+a_2b_2\ge a_1b_2+a_2b_1=\sin^2\cdot  \frac{4}{ \sin^2 x}+ \frac 94\cdot4=13$$

Comment: this is wrong，you can not do like this，unless you can go on with the sencond inequality.

Comment: @mengdie1982 Yes of course you are right! I fix, thanks